# MySql SELECT DISTINCT(x) AS Column1,COUNT(DISTINCT(y)) as Column2 FROM sample.database GROUP BY Column1 query failed

Tags: mysql

I need help with mysql query. Namely, I would like to display a result that in the first column contains unique values ​​for example let be a quarter and in the second column the sum of unique quantities of products. The following query throws a connection to the database. I would like to ask for advice and help.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(Quarter) AS Column1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Product)) as Column2 FROM sample.database
    GROUP BY Column1;
```

Sample table below:

```
id  Quarter     Month           Product
1   Q4 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 1
2   Q4 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 1
3   Q4 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 2
4   Q3 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 3
5   Q3 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 3
6   Q3 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 4
7   Q3 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 4
8   Q3 2016  2016-10-01 00:00   Sample 4
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There's no x here.

Answer (score 0):

if the "sum of unique values" means distinct count of unique values then you can use:

```
select Quarter, count(distinct Product)
from data
group by Quarter
```

Comment: Sorry for my English.
An error occurs with this syntax :#2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Comment: That is a separate problem. The query itself is ok. Look for the possible causes for the #2006 error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `DISTINCT` for column 1 as `GROUP BY` will do it for you, try the following query:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(DISTINCT y)
FROM table
GROUP BY x;
```